# Looking for some ideas with how to reformat spreadsheet type data (excel, easymorph, etc..)

Tags: excel, csv, spreadsheet

I have spreadsheet data in the following format:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sHY5.png)

Any row that has MULTIPLE 335xxxxxxx numbers separated by commas, I need to change into separate rows with a single 335xxxxxxx number.  So lori rogers for example, I need to duplicate six times and create a separate row for every one of those 335xxxxxxx numbers.

And Nicholas Rogers at the bottom, I would need to duplicate that row one more time and make one row with 3352102937, and another row with 3352105545.

I have thousands and thousands of rows like this that need to be done, so I am trying to find a formula or a way to somehow automate the process instead of spending days and weeks doing this manually.

Any ideas of a program or a script or something that could do it?

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, Data tab, Get & Transform Data From Table/Range.

When Power Query opens, Split Column by Delimiter, Split into Rows

[image]